# Step-by-Step How-to on Mediation Analysis in R

Tags: r, algorithm, statistics

I'd like to know if anybody can provide a step-by-step how to on how to use mediation analysis using [Keele, Tingley, Yamamoto and Imai's mediation package](http://imai.princeton.edu/software/mediation.html). I think there are two approaches to this - [the classic Baron and Kenny (1986)](http://www.public.asu.edu/~davidpm/classes/psy536/Baron.pdf) and the new one by [Preacher, Rucker and Hayes (2007)](http://kuscholarworks.ku.edu/dspace/bitstream/1808/1658/1/preacher_rucker_hayes_2007.pdf) - I'd like to know how to do both approaches in R

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case you not familiar with R and packages, start with

```
install.packages(mediation)
```

to download and install the package from CRAN. Then do

```
library(help=mediation)
```

for a high-level view of the package, and available help files. Then use

```
library(mediation)
help(mediate)
```

to load the package and read the help page.  The example can be run via

```
example(mediate)
```

and you can run the other example for sensitivity analysis via

```
example(medsens)
```

Comment: @Dirk I've actually done this already - do you recommend any test dataset that I can run the mediation package on?

Answer (score 3):

This [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mediation/vignettes/mediation.pdf) is what you are looking for, if the above answer isn't enough.

It's about as hand-holdy as you can get with this sort of thing.

Comment: thanks for this! https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mediation/vignettes/mediation.pdf answers my question to Dirk on what test dataset I can use - on page 5 of the PDF, they mention Brader, Valentino and Suhat (2008)'s framing data that can be used via:

R>library("mediation")
R>set.seed(2014)
R>data("framing", package="mediation")
R>framing?